# Nested Serializer with 3 Foreign Key. How to implement GET and POST?

Tags: django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

```
class Author(models.Model):

   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   age = models.IntegerField()
```

//

```
class Editor(models.Model):

   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   date_edition = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

   status = models.BooleaField(default=True)
```

//

```
class Book_Manufacturer(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   year_production = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

//

```
class Book(models.Model):

   author = models.models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   editor = models.models.ForeignKey(Editor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   book_manufacturer = models.models.ForeignKey(Book_Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   year = models.DateTime(default=datetime.now)
```

Can anyone help me? How I would serializer a Book with 3 foreign_key and show all details when I have a GET method? (Al details = Book details + Book_Manufacturer + Editor + Author)

Also what about the POST method, how would it be implemented If I want to create a Book with all the information?

PS: In the real application I have a model with 3 foreign key, just like the exemple. I used a example here with a naive approach, it's not my real model fields and class names XD, is just a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BookSimpleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('author', 'editor', 'book_manufacturer', 'title', 'year')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Book(**validated_data)
```

Comment: for view use generics.CreateAPIView

Comment: My other views are Viewsets, there will be any problem If I use Viewsets?

Comment: I'm not comfortable with Viewsets and always use generics or pure APIView. but you can test it.

Answer (score 1):

you can define serializer like this:

But for create a new Book, you can define create method in BookSerializer and create all new obj on there

```
class AuthorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'age')

class EditorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Editor
        fields = ('first_name', 'date_edition', 'status')

class Book_ManufacturerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book_Manufacturer
        fields = ('name', 'year_production')


class BookSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    author = AuthorSerializer()
    editor = EditorSerializer()
    book_manufacturer = Book_ManufacturerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('author', 'editor', 'book_manufacturer', 'title', 'year')
   def create(self, validated_data):
       author = validated_data.pop('author')
       editor = validated_data.pop('editor')
       book_manufacturer = validated_data.pop('book_manufacturer')

       author_obj = Author.objects.create(first_name=author['first_name'], last_name=author['last_name'])

       # do it for editor and book_manufacturer
       book = Book.objects.create(author=author_obj, editor=editor_obj, book_manufacturer=book_manufacturer_obj, title=validated_data['title'], year=validated_data['year'])

       return validated_data
```

Comment: With this implementation in the moment I'm creating a Book, it will give me the option to use a Author that is in the database or it will ask me to create a new Author?

Comment: It create a new author for example. but if you want author list from db, you should use another approach.

Comment: I going to write now

Comment: Yep, in the application I need to use the author list from db.